# Inbuilt / pre-defined comparator in cpp

Tags: c++, comparator, std

Recently I learnt about comparators in cpp from STL.

I came to know we can use `greater<>()` as third argument for sorting instead of writing own logic.

Just curious to know how many inbuilt comparators are there in cpp.

Comment: [A good C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) might be useful.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard library defines pretty much what you would expect as analogues to the built-in operators:

```
std::equal_to      // ==
std::not_equal_to  // !=
std::less          // <
std::less_equal    // <=
std::greater       // >
std::greater_equal // >=
```

Since C++20 also constrained versions of all these comparison function objects in the `std::ranges` namespace as well as `std::compare_­three_­way`, which is the analogue to the built-in three-way comparison operator `<=>`.

For a reference of these function objects see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional#Comparisons.